# Passing value to class that doesn't extends Activity (Android)

Tags: android

Here are two classes-SecondActivity and AnimationView.
  SecondActivity extends Activity and AnimationView extends View.I want to pass the value of "text" from one SecondActivity to AnimationView..

I want to use string "text" in AnimationView class.So I need to pass its value from SecondActivity class to AnimationView class.I was trying to do it through intent..But I think its not possible through intent as AnimationView doesn't extend Activity

SecondActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    AnimationView animationview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = getIntent(); 
        String text = i.getStringExtra("TextBox"); 
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnimationView.class);
        in.putExtra("abc", text);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        animationview=(AnimationView)findViewById(R.id.animationView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

AnimationView.java

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
public class AnimationView extends View{
  private final int FRAME_RATE=15;
  private Paint paint;
  private Handler h;
  Ball myball;
  Ball greenball;
  Ball redball;


    public AnimationView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        h=new Handler();
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
        greenball=new Ball(200,200,Color.GREEN,50);
        redball=new Ball(50,400,Color.RED,50);
        myball.setDX(10);
        myball.setDY(10);
        greenball.setDX(10);
        greenball.setDY(10);
        redball.setDX(10);
        redball.setDY(10);

    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        myball.bounce(c);
        greenball.bounce(c);
        redball.bounce(c);
        myball.bounceoff(myball);
        greenball.bounceoff(greenball);
        redball.bounceoff(redball);


        c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
        c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
        c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());

        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);

    }
    private Runnable r=new Runnable()
    { public void run()
    { invalidate();
    }
    };
    }
```

Comment: You can pass value  to the constructor of the view class

Comment: @Raghunandan: obviously not. the view is clearly created in the xml layout.

Comment: @njzk2 right. din't see this `animationview=(AnimationView)findViewById(R.id.animationView);`

Comment: What are you trying to do with this intent ? (just add a setter method to your view.)

Comment: You could make your view class an inner class of Activity also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnimationView.class);
in.putExtra("abc", text);
```

does not work. Its not a Activity class

You can have a setter method

```
String value;
public void setString(String value)
{
   this.value = value;
}
```

Then

```
animationview.setString(text);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but you might change the "not needed" comment on using an Intent to "not workable"

Comment: Thank you very much Raghunandan